# Term for a map of constants

Tags: terminology, constants

Considering there's a map of string constants, most commonly with a key and a value being equal, e.g. in TypeScript:

```
const itemTypes = {
  FOO_BAR: 'FOO_BAR',
  BAZ_QUX: 'BAZ_QUX',
} as const;
```

They are supposed to be used with a specified domain (item type) and can benefit from being referred as keys on `itemTypes`, for both compilation and runtime type safety.

I failed to search for specific code-related solutions to my problems with such maps of constants because this name isn't descriptive enough, while "enum" is a related concept but primarily used with integer values.

I wonder if there's a conventional term for it.

Answer (score 3):

The terminology you're looking for is "*enumerated type*" or simply "*enum*" in most programming languages.

---

To directly quote the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) on the term:

> In computer programming, an enumerated type (also called enumeration, enum, or factor in the R programming language, and a categorical variable in statistics) is a data type consisting of a set of named values called elements, members, enumeral, or enumerators of the type. The enumerator names are usually identifiers that behave as constants in the language.

Languages like C# make this clear when you declare them:

```
public enum CardSuit {
    None = 0,
    Spades = 1,
    Clubs = 2,
    Diamonds = 3,
    Hearts = 4
}
```

Keep in mind, not all languages support enumerated types having values, and some only support specific value types such as integers. `JavaScript` does (which is why `TypeScript` supports it) but for example, your code snippet would be invalid in C# and would need to be written as:

```
public enum ItemTypes {
    FooBar,
    BazQux
}
```

Furthermore, `JavaScript` and `TypeScript` support *any* type for enumerated type values; for example in `TypeScript`:

```
const itemTypes = {
  FOO_BAR: {
      FOO: 'FOO',
      BAR: 'BAR'
  },
  BAZ_QUX: 'BAZ_QUX',
} as const;
```

This is just as valid as your example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I mentioned in the OP that integer enums are most common ones for a good reason, but not exactly what I asked about. String enum is a special case (also supported in TS with `enum` syntax), I assume there may be no more specific term for that.

Comment: Since this answer mentions C#, you may be interested in https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2849. This was a discussion around supporting string-based enums in C#. It was never championed by a member of the language design team, so is unlikely to ever happen, but it's still an interesting read of the topic.

Comment: @EstusFlask, I think you have an overly optimistic view on the ability of software engineering to come up with specific terms here. After all, the term "enumeration" is overloaded in eg C# to mean collections of data like lists and arrays (`IEnumerable<T>`) and of collections of values (`enum` types). "String-based enums" is about as specific as you'll likely get.

Comment: @DavidArno I remember this hub when it was just `programmers`. Yes, thanks, for the link, the discussion is on-topic. Good to know about the state of things in #. The term "strongly typed strings" that was coined isn't conventional but makes sense.

Comment: @EstusFlask JS and TS don't specifically support `string` values in enumerated types; rather, they support *any* type value in enumerated types.

Comment: @Tacoタコス As for TS `enum` syntax, it only supports integers and strings but provides no restrictions on string value, something that I needed to implement.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, for the [enum keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) in TS; but that's not what was in your question.